# Kerberos login with multiples domains

Tags: authentication, active-directory, kerberos, keycloak, spnego

I'm trying to configure a login through Kerberos using Keycloak (WildFly 11), server is installed in a Windows 2016 and has MIT Kerberos acting as a Kerberos client, domains are Active Directories.

I have generated a keytab file from domain ABC and I'm able to login using Kerberos with users from that domain (SPN is HTTP/url.com@ABC). The keytab file is generated using a user in domain ABC, but I have added another SPN from domain XYZ (HTTP/url.com@XYZ).
I have another domain, XYZ that has a trust relationship with ABC. Users from that domain can't login using Kerberos as the negotiation gives this error "KRB5KDC_ERR_S_PRINCIPAL_UNKNOWN".

I guess that the problem is that users from ABC are negotiating tickets with ABC domain and that domain has the SPN setted correctly, and users from XYZ are negotiating tickets with XYZ domain and that domain doesn't have the SPN configured.

This is the MIT Kerberos client configuration:

```
[realms]
 ABC = {
  kdc = abcdom:88
  admin_server = abcdom:749
  default_domain = ABC
 }

 XYZ = {
  kdc = xyzdom:88
  admin_server = xyzdom:749
 }


[domain_realm]
 .url.com = ABC
 url.com = ABC
 .url.com = XYZ
 url.com = XYZ
```

My question is, do I have to generate a keytab file for each domain? How can I add the SPN to XYZ domain?
There is a cross trust between domains.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You need to join your node with both ABC and XYZ in order to get expected result. While login user has to mention u1@ABC or u2@XYZ so it can be redirected to correct domain for authentication. Are you using SSSD by any chance? You should configure these Domains there and allow them to login.

Comment: No, I'm not using SSSD, just MIT Kerberos as client in a Windows 2016 Server where Keycloak is running. When you say "need to join your node" means that I need a keytab file for each domain?